# Find volume of a solid

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Find the volume of the solid generated when the region enclosed by $y=\sqrt{x+1}$ , $y=\sqrt{3x}$ and $y=0$ is revolved about the $x$-axis. [Hint: Split the solid into two parts.]

I got $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ as an answer but Webwork keeps rejecting it. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show some work?:)

Comment: y=sqrt(x+1) intersects with y=sqrt(3x) at x=1/2
y=sqrt(x+1) has a zero at x=-1
y=sqrt(3x) has a zero at x=0
So V= pi(integral(x+1)dx) from -1 to 0
           plus
           pi(integral(x+1 - 3x)dx) from 0 to 1/2
       = (3/4)pi

Comment: @JayTee: I am also getting the answer as $\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be straight forward but Webwork keeps rejecting it. :-(

Comment: Screw Webwork. You are right.